# Opening PDF in Phonegap (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, pdf

I have tried for some time to figure this out but I cannot get a solution. I have a local PDF that I need to open either in the app itself or in a 3rd party app (whatever works). I need to have it so that no other applications need to be downloaded for it to work. Does anyone know a good solution for this? I have tried inAppBrowser and some other javascript solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi You can open the file with the FileOpener plugin, open a PDF document with the default PDF reader app.

[File opener plugin](https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2)

Install:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```

Usage:

```
cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
    '/sdcard/Download/starwars.pdf', // You can also use a Cordova-style file uri: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/Download/starwars.pdf
    'application/pdf', 
    { 
        error : function(e) { 
            console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
        },
        success : function () {
            console.log('file opened successfully');                
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, do you know how to disable all permissions that the Android app requires?